# React-native-phone-input not getting blur callback

Tags: android, react-native, formik

I am using react-native-phone-input(1.0.10).I've form with use of other fields like (input, radio, select)and all fields validate by formik and yup in react native.
Rest of the fields working properly with onchange and onblur event but phone-input not return any callback on blur property by itself

When I press "Signup" button at that time getting error message that "phone-number is required".when I input value to the phone number field so error message not longer available (That's correct) But When I removed value on phone input field and focus on the other field so at that time no any error message display for phone number field

I am attaching code for input field

```
                     <Input
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      keyboardType={'email-address'}
                      value={values.email}
                      onChangeText={e => {
                        setFieldValue('email', e, (values.phoneNumber = ''));
                      }}
                      // onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                      onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                      label={evaProps => <Text {...evaProps}>{'Email '}</Text>}
                    />
                    {errors.email && touched.email && (
                      <Text style={styles.commonErrorText}>{errors.email}</Text>
                    )}
                    <PhoneInput
                      ref={ref => {
                        phone = ref;
                      }}
                      textStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                      style={{marginHorizontal: 10}}
                      autoFormat={true}
                      // onChangePhoneNumber={text => {
                      //   setPhoneNumber(text);
                      // }}
                      onChangePhoneNumber={e => {
                        setFieldValue(
                          'phoneNumber',
                          e,
                          setFieldError(errors.email, ''),
                          (values.email = '')
                        );
                      }}
                      onSelectCountry={data => onSelectCountry(data)}
                      value={values.phoneNumber}
                      initialCountry={countryData.cca2.toLowerCase()}
                      textProps={{placeholder: 'Telephone number'}}
                      onPressFlag={onPressFlag}
                    />
```

Formik validation:

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape(
  {
   
    email: Yup.string().when('phoneNumber', {
      is: phoneNumber => !phoneNumber || phoneNumber.length === 0,
      then: Yup.string()
        .email('Please enter a valid email address')
        .matches(emailRegExp, 'Please enter a valid email address')
        .required('Email is required'),
    }),
    phoneNumber: Yup.string().when('email', {
      is: email => !email || email.length === 0,
      then: Yup.string()
        // .matches(phoneRegExp, 'Phone number is not valid')
        .required('Mobile number is required')
        .max(20, 'Mobile number is too long'),
    })
  ['email', 'phoneNumber'],
);

      <Formik
          initialValues={{
            email: '',
            phoneNumber: ''
          }}
          validationSchema={SignupSchema}
          onSubmit={values => {
           console.log("values");
          }}>
          {({
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            values,
            errors,
            setFieldValue,
            setFieldError,
            touched,
          })
```

Submit-button code:

```
 <Button status="success" onPress={handleSubmit}>
                      Register Now
                    </Button>
```

I am stuck on this issue